# Python - Nested Loops with CSVs

Tags: python, csv, match

I've had a bit of trouble trying to match some data from some CSVs. I've got some example CSVs below with a basic structure of the data I'm using.

I am attempting to match the values from column A in CSV 2, to those of column E in CSV 1, and then if they match, write the row from CSV 1 to a new CSV.

**Code**

```
with open(CSV1,"r") as f, open(CSV2,"r") as g, open("Match.csv","w",newline='') as h:
    rdr1 = csv.reader(f)
    rdr2 = csv.reader(g)
    wtr = csv.writer(h)
    for r in rdr1:
        for s in rdr2: 
            if (s[0] == r[4]):
                print("match")
```

I am using a dataset with 100,000s of rows so there are more matches and matches are repeated a few times. In this example, there is only one occasion where it matches twice (92).

With my code, I presume that I'm looping through all the rows in my first CSV, and for each row, I am looping through all the rows in the 2nd CSV. If the values are equal, I print 'match'.

The problem I have is that it only prints 'match' once at most. I've tried to think about it, but I'm pretty much stuck at this point. Shouldn't the console print 'match' everytime the value s[0] is equal to that of r[4] - in this example, this happens multiple times.

I'd like to ensure that everytime there is a match, the writer writes a new row in my output CSV, however I simply only get the first match. Help!

**CSV 1**

```
A   B       C           D           E
A   Test1   0.101534549 0.590695315 95
B   Test2   0.8264073   0.120144407 44
C   Test3   0.977242848 0.067444475 97
D   Test4   0.270980415 0.524929719 62
E   Test5   0.059128388 0.260576647 36
F   Test6   0.571208391 0.246145371 85
G   Test7   0.098088188 0.618968191 91
H   Test8   0.898575649 0.56778217  88
I   Test9   0.233745198 0.514747763 2
J   Test10  0.452100086 0.749702553 97
K   Test11  0.493666064 0.002437728 80
L   Test12  0.052633239 0.864048743 22
M   Test13  0.635517951 0.716967917 21
N   Test14  0.921723813 0.766473275 22
O   Test15  0.54634609  0.853116802 92
P   Test16  0.400754273 0.993727094 61
Q   Test17  0.549368986 0.868975583 46
R   Test18  0.301279637 0.222360597 65
S   Test19  0.152111468 0.698786954 1
T   Test20  0.313768676 0.354556772 21
```

**CSV 2**

```
A
29
7
52
66
27
91
27
33
84
85
41
92
80
22
15
61
62
17
21
92
```

Comment: any reason you're not using `pandas` to just perform an inner join and then write out to csv?

Comment: I've never used pandas. I'll have a look

Comment: The issue is that rdr1 and rdr2 are iterators, and rdr2 is exhausted since you iterate over it completely in the first iteration of rdr2. But yes, use pandas.

Comment: Okay, will look into it. Just got into data analysis with python a week ago, so all new to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
with open(CSV1, 'r') as f, open(CSV2, 'r') as g, open('Match.csv', 'w', newline='') as h:
    rdr1 = csv.reader(f)
    rdr2 = csv.reader(g)
    wtr = csv.writer(h)

    # build up a set of everything in CSV2
    haystack = set()
    for i, line in enumerate(rdr2):
        if i == 0:
            continue # skip header line
        haystack.add(line[0])

    # check each line for a match in our set
    for line in rdr1:
        needle = line[4]
        if needle in haystack:
            wtr.writerow(line)
```

It keeps the same basic idea that you are doing, but reads one whole file into a set (named haystack) that we then check for membership of the target cell (named needle).

As Shiva and some commenters pointed out, the problem was the file-pointer of `g` was not being reset to the beginning with each new iteration. This solution sidesteps the rewind by only reading the file once.

Comment: Done! Thats my first question I've asked so i'm new to this!

Comment: np ... and glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The mistake in your code is that `g` needs to be rewound back to the beginning of the file in each loop and you need to call `csv_reader` on it each time you rewind. Like this:

```
for r in rdr1:
    g.seek(0)          # seek to the beginning of the file
    s = csv.reader(g)  # restart iterator
    for s in rdr2:
        if s[0] == r[4]:
            print("match")
```

A faster solution than having to rewind back to the beginning of the file each time (which can be an expensive operation) is to read all the lines into local variables and then perform a set-like "intersection" using list comprehensions. Like this:

```
with open(CSV1) as f, open(CSV2) as g, open('foo-match.csv', 'w') as h:
    lines1 = [line.split(',') for line in f]
    lines2 = [line.split(',') for line in g]
    commonlineindices = [i1 for (i1, row1) in enumerate(lines1) for row2 in lines2 if row1[4]==row2[0]]
    print(commonlineindices)
    h.writelines([','.join(lines1[index]) for index in commonlineindices])
```

This computes the indices of rows that you need. Once you have this, it's straightforward to print out those corresponding rows.